# Cannot see a perforce version controlled file in my workspace

Tags: perforce, p4v

I had made changes to a file and then shelved it.
Then I deleted the file.

Now I am not able to get it back to my workspace. I tried p4 sync -f and p4 unshelve ##.

What do I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p4 unshelve is the correct command.

To figure out which shelf you need to unshelve, use p4 changes -s shelved and p4 describe -S

What's probably going wrong is that when you deleted the file, you still left it "opened" in Perforce (do p4 opened to see), so first do a p4 revert to revert the file, then you can successfully unshelve the shelf and you'll get your edited version back.

Answer (score -1):

In p4v, go to the depot view, select the file, then hit ctrl-shift-s (pretty sure this works in linux too) this will open an explorer window which should be where the file is located. Maybe it's going to a different directory then the one you think?

If it's not there, right click the folder, and say get this revision, and check the force checkbox

Comment: Please indicate what are you trying to tell me to do. What does Ctrl Shift s does ?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, it will open an explorer window to show you where perforce thinks the file is supposed to be, that way you can be sure you're in the right directory.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu p4v. I am not able to carry out any of your suggested actions.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-s still works in Redhat, so it probably works in Ubuntu as well. You can also still right click, and say get revision, then check the "force" checkbox. You tagged the question with p4v, so I assume your using it?